# How to extract specific lemma or pos/tag using spacy?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, token, spacy

I am using spacy to lemmatize and parse a list of sentences. the data are contained in an excel file.

I would like to write a function which allow me to return different lemma of my sentences.

For example returning only lemma with a specific tag ("VERB" OR "VERB" +"ADJ")

This is my code :

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.fr import French
from spacy_lefff import LefffLemmatizer, POSTagger
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
nlp=spacy.load('fr')
parser = French()


path = 'Gold.xlsx'
my_sheet ="Gold"
df = read_excel(path, sheet_name= my_sheet)

def tokenizeTexte(sample):
    tokens = parser(sample)
    lemmas = []
    for tok in tokens:
        lemmas.append((tok.lemma_.lower(), tok.tag_, tok.pos_))
    tokens = lemmas
    tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in stopwords]
    return tokens



df['Preprocess_verbatim'] = df.apply(lambda row:tokenizeTexte(row['verbatim']), axis=1) 

print(df)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

I would like to be able to return all lemma with for example "verb" or "adj" or "adv" tag and then modify to return all the lemma.

I also wish to return different combination of lemma ( "PRON" +" "VERB"+"ADJ")

How can i do that with spacy ?

this is what i obtain with my code

```
       id                        ...                                                        Preprocess_verbatim
0     463                        ...                          [(ce, , ), (concept, , ), (résoudre, , ), (que...
1    2647                        ...                          [(alors, , ), (ça, , ), (vouloir, , ), (dire, ...
2    5391                        ...                          [(ça, , ), (ne, , ), (changer, , ), (rien, , )...
3    1120                        ...                          [(sur, , ), (le, , ), (station, , ), (de, , ),
```

tok.tag and tok.pos does not appear , do you know why?

My file :

example of my data :

```
id verbatim

14   L'économe originellement est donc celui qui a la responsabilité, pour des      personnes d'une maison, d'une unité d'organisation donnée .  
25   De leur donner des rations de ressources au temps opportun. 
56   Contrairement à l'idée qu'on se fait l'économe n'est pas axé sur le capital, c'est-à-dire sur l'action de capitaliser, mais sur les individus d'une unité organisation, c'est-à-dire sur l'action de partager, de redistribuer d'une façon juste et opportune des ressources aux différents membre
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  That way someone could copy and paste your code into their editor.

Comment: @JeffTilton I added a  an example of my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think your model isn't working correctly because you're defining the `nlp` object twice. I believe you only need it once. I am also not sure what `parser` is doing and I'm not sure you need it. For this code, I would use something like the following:

```
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp(sample)
tokens = [tok for tok in doc]
```

Then, `doc` is a spacy `Doc` object, and `tokens` is a list of spaCy `Token` objects. From here, the loop that iterates over your tokens would work.

If you want to do the POS selection in your existing preprocessing function, I think you only need to change one line in your loop:

```
for tok in tokens:
    if tok.pos_ in ("VERB", "ADJ", "ADV"):
       lemmas.append((tok.lemma_.lower(), tok.tag_, tok.pos_))
```

This will only add tokens with those specific parts of speech to your `lemmas` list.

I also noticed another issue in your code on this line further down:

```
tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in stopwords]
```

At this point `tok` is your tuple of `(lemma, tag, pos)`, so unless your list of `stopwords` is tuples of the same format, and not only lemmas or tokens you want to exclude, this step will not exclude anything.

Putting it all together, you'd have something like this, which would return a list of tuples of `(lemma, tag, pos)` if the POS is correct:

```
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")

stopwords = ["here", "are", "some", "stopwords"]

def tokenizeTexte(sample):
    doc = nlp(sample)
    lemmas = []
    for tok in tokens:
        if tok.pos_ in ("VERB", "ADJ", "ADV"):
            lemmas.append((tok.lemma_.lower(), tok.tag_, tok.pos_))
    tokens = [(lemma, tag, pos) for (lemma, tag, pos) in lemmas if lemma not in stopwords]
    return tokens
```

Comment: my stopword list is not in a form of tuple but one word per line in a txt file and as expected , they are not excludes , any idea how to counter that, furthermore, spacy do not get the correct pos or lemma for some words in french, is it possible to correct it ?

Comment: You could use a larger model like `fr_core_news_md` to get better POS tagging performance. You should know that you'll never have perfect accuracy, however. 

The final code example I gave will exclude any words in stopwords if `stopwords` is a list.

Comment: thank you, I tried your proposition but for the stopword is not working , I am certain is because my list look like this : [ b'Yanagida', b'Yandell', b'Yanosik', b'Yarbrough', b'Yarnell', b'Yazdani', b'Yearwood']  I took it from a txt.file   So to load it I do this  :  path = '/home/k/Documents/XP/ressources/MotsVides.txt'
file = open(path, mode='rb')
stopwords = file.read()
stopwords = [x.strip() for x in stopwords]
print(stopwords)   In my stoplist file each word correspond to one line. I tried to transform it to a list but when I ma using it the script does not remove the word

Comment: try using open(path, mode='r') - I'm not sure if its an issue that it's reading them as binary strings or not.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer when you can, @EMMAKENJI

Comment: I did accept     but sadly I do not have enough reputation to cast votes (+1). but as soon as i have i will do it